# Refactoring; creating pseudo-primitives for your application domain

Tags: c#

How would you refactor this, keeping in mind that you have dozens more of such measurements to represent? It's kind of like changing an int to short or long or byte. Generic `unit<T>`? Implicit type conversion by via operator overloading? `ToType()` pattern? Abstract base class? `IConvertible`?

```
public class lb
{
    private readonly float lbs;
    private readonly kg kgs;

    public lb(float lbs)
    {
        this.lbs = lbs;
        this.kgs = new kg(lbs * 0.45359237F);
    }

    public kg ToKg()
    {
        return this.kgs; 
    }

    public float ToFloat()
    {
        return this.lbs;
    }
}

public class kg 
{
    private readonly float kgs;
    private readonly lb lbs;

    public kg(float kgs)
    {
        this.kgs = kgs;
        this.lbs = new lb(kgs * 2.20462262F);
    }

    public float ToFloat()
    {
        return this.kgs;
    }

    public lb ToLb()
    {
        return this.lbs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't create separate classes for each weight.  Instead, have one class that represents a unit and another that represents a number with a unit:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class representing a unit of weight, including how to
/// convert that unit to kg.
/// </summary>
class WeightUnit
{
    private readonly float conv;
    private readonly string name;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a weight unit
    /// </summary>
    WeightUnit(float conv, string name)
    {
        this.conv = conv;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the name of the unit
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get { return name; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the multiplier used to convert this
    /// unit into kg
    /// </summary>
    public float convToKg { get { return conv; } }
};

/// <summary>
/// Class representing a weight, i.e., a number and a unit.
/// </summary>
class Weight
{
    private readonly float value;
    private readonly WeightUnit unit;

    public Weight(float value, WeightUnit unit)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public float ToFloat()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public WeightUnit Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Weight object that is the same value
    /// as this object, but in the given units.
    /// </summary>
    public Weight Convert(WeightUnit newUnit)
    {
        float newVal = value * unit.convToKg / newUnit.convToKg;

        return new Weight(newVal, newUnit);
    }
};
```

The nice thing here is that you can create all the WeightUnits as singleton objects from data, perhaps an XML file or resource, so that you can add a new unit without changing any code at all.  Creating a Weight object is just a matter of looking up the correct singleton by name.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll just turn it into an `struct`, which most primitives are anyway.

Comment: I hate the fact that I have to use System.Nullable<> (e.g. use the ?) to represent null structs. The resources that could be saved by using a struct are less important than the design in this scenario.

Comment: Ahh, so you want a nullable type. That figures. The only problem I have with your current design is the tight coupling between lb and kg; what if, in the future, I want to put in ton, tonne, newton, ounce, gram, etc?